# Angular datepicker translate

Tags: angularjs, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using Angular bootstrap datepicker, only problem i have with translate, because I am using multilanguage application.

The problem I have is with button translate, i know i can easy translate CLOSE, and Reset button, but Today always stay the same, if I try somthing like this

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" value="22-22-2222"
                                   uib-datepicker-popup="{{model.dateFormat}}"
                                   ng-model="model.project.startDate"
                                   is-open="model.startDateProjectPickerOpened"
                                   close-text="Zatvori"
                                   today-text="Danas"
                                   clear-text="Obrisi"
                                   alt-input-formats="altInputFormats"
                                   name="projectStartDate"
                                   required
                                   ng-class="{'error':submitted && addNewProjectForm.projectStartDate.$invalid}" />
```

I got this

[image]

Only blue button didnt change value, even if i have tried **today-text="Danas"**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `current-text` insted of `today-text`

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" value="22-22-2222"
                                   uib-datepicker-popup="{{model.dateFormat}}"
                                   ng-model="model.project.startDate"
                                   is-open="model.startDateProjectPickerOpened"
                                   close-text="Zatvori"
                                   current-text="Danas"
                                   clear-text="Obrisi"
                                   alt-input-formats="altInputFormats"
                                   name="projectStartDate"
                                   required
                                   ng-class="{'error':submitted && addNewProjectForm.projectStartDate.$invalid}" />
```